# Inline convert list of long? to an string including comma separator

Tags: c#, string, lambda

I have a list of long. I want to have a string containing this values separated by comma separator. I have to do it inline, using lambda expression.

```
branch[0] = 1234;
branch[1] = 6789;
...
var theValue=? I NEED "1234,6789"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to use a *lambda expression*, you can use [`String.Join<T>(String,IEnumerable<T>)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var theValue = String.Join(",",branch);
```

Sample with the `csharp` interactive shell:

```
csharp> var branch = new int[2];
csharp> branch[0] = 1234;
csharp> branch[1] = 6789;
csharp> String.Join(",",branch)
"1234,6789"
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm agree with Willem Van Onsem, but if you still want a LINQ solution

```
     var branch = new int[2];

        branch[0] = 1234;
        branch[1] = 6789;

        var l = branch.Select((x, i) =>
        {
            if (branch.Length-1 > i)
            {
                return new { res = branch[i].ToString() + ',' + branch[i+1].ToString() };
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        });
     Console.WriteLine(l.ToArray()[0].res);
```